# Twitter Bootstrap: Extra 2px padding when I give btn-group a background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to give a gradiented border to a button group (that has exactly 4 elements and should fill up the width of its container) but it gets an extra padding of 2 pixels when I add a background/padding to it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjA2U/

Any recommendations how I can work around this? Would I have to resort to not using those classes at all?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bootstrap puts a margin-left of -1 px on each button. The container is the sum of the widths of the children, so you'll need to either remove the negative margin on the child buttons, or set a fixed width on the container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your width rule. You have given the width in %. `Placeholder` width is 80% and each `.btn` width is 25%. This is not fitting your button there.

Change in CSS:

```
.btn-group .btn {
    width: 25.2%;
}​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/wjA2U/1/)

**Note:** It is better to use fixed width.

Comment: You can ignore the placeholder markup/css. I just used it to not make the whole thing stick to the edges, but I _do_ need it to be fluid and not have a specific width.